# Copy Folders Recursively: Shell

Tags: shell, directory, copy

My code takes two arguments from the user. My goal is to find the folder given by the user (the first argument) and make as many copies as they want of it (the second argument). As of right now, my code recursively prints out all subdirectories and files within the subdirectories... My code also copies files as many times as the user specifies. However, that's my problem, my copy function only works on files and not folders... I am wondering how to modify my copy function (or any other part of the code) so that it recursively copies the specified folder along with all of its original content

I know my cp function towards the bottom of the code needs to be changed to
-r ./sourceFolder ./destFolder but I do not know how to do that given the arguments passed in. After all, the destination folder name will just be the original folder with an incrementing number at the end of it.

```
#!/bin/bash


read -p "Your folder name is $1 and the number of copies is $2. Press Y for yes N for no " -n 1 -r
if ! [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
echo
echo "Rerun script and pass in the folder and how many copies yo would like (e.g folder 4)"
exit
fi
echo 
echo "-------------COPY FILE----------------"

FOLDER=$1
for f IN $folder
do
if [ ! -f "$FOLDER" ]
then
echo "folder "$FOLDER" does not exist"
exit 1 
fi 
done

DIR="."

function list_files()
{

cd $1
echo; echo "$(pwd)":; #Display Directory name

for i in *
do
if test -d "$i" #if dictionary
then 
list_files "$i" #recursively list files
cd ..
else
echo "$i"; #Display File name
fi

done
}

j=$2
for i in "$*"
do
DIR=$1 
list_files "$DIR"

 for ((i=1; i<J; i++))
do
cp "$1" "$1$i"; #copies the file i amount of times, and creates new files with names that increment by 1
done
shift 1
done
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `if test -d "$1"`?

Comment: Yes... the errors state cp: cannot stat 'folder' - no such file or directory found... And I'm pretty sure the folder I passed in exists

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy recursive you can use `cp -r <source folder> <destination folder>`.
This will copy the content of the source file to the destination folder.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Your folder name is $1 and the number of copies is $2. Press Y for yes N for no " -n 1 -r
if ! [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
echo
echo "Rerun script and pass in the folder and how many copies yo would like (e.g folder 4)"
exit
fi
echo 
echo "-------------COPY FILE----------------"

FOLDER=$1
if [ ! -d "$FOLDER" ]
then
echo "folder  $FOLDER does not exist"
exit 1 
fi

j=$2
for ((i=1; i<=j; i++))
do
cp  -r "$1" "$1$i"; #copies the file i amount of times, and creates new files with names that increment by 1
echo "folder $1 copied to $1$i"
done
```

I changed the folder check from `-f` to `-d`, changed the variable nameing a bit (case), removed the `list_files` function and changed in the last for loop the `i<$j` to `i<=j` because the loop starts with `1`. Then I added the -r and it works.

Comment: I've tried that.... didn't work unfortunately. The code still runs, but nothing happens. No copies are made of anything now

Comment: I think it didn't work because you change the case of the variables (for example you initialise `j` (lowercase) and use it in the for loop as `J`' (uppercase)).

Comment: When I pass a folder into your code, I get the error cp:cannot stat 'testfolder': No such file or directory....

Comment: are you sure the folder exists?